# how to get filename from Content-Disposition header using dart http.Response?

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I am downloading a file from a server with a GET request. Like this.

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

    final http.Response response = await http.get(uri, headers: headers);
    if (response.isOk()) {
      response.headers.forEach((key, value) {
        print('key = $key; value = $value');
      });

      final Uint8List bytes = response.bodyBytes;

      AnchorElement(href: "$contentPrefix${base64Encode(bytes)}")
        ..setAttribute("download", "file.xlsx")
        ..click();
    } else {
      print('report request status code is ${response.statusCode}');
    }
```

I need to know the file name.

The file name is contained in the `content-disposition` header, in different encodings. But it is not in `http.Response.headers`.
How to extract filename in `UTF-8` encoding?

[image]

Comment: I think you need to get your server to add content-disposition to the `access-control-expose-headers`. It seems the server isn't including this header at all. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now I have access to it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only certain HTTP response headers are available to cross site XHR requests, as would be the case in a Flutter Web application making a request from a server that didn't launch it. Such a request firstly needs the relevant CORS headers, but if you want to be able to access one of the non-default response headers, also needs the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header.

The CORS-safelisted response headers are: `Cache-Control`, `Content-Language`, `Content-Length`, `Content-Type`, `Expires`, `Last-Modified`, `Pragma`. Since `Content-Disposition` isn't a safelisted header, your server will need to emit:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition
```

The `Content-Disposition` header will then appear in `response.headers`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Richard Heap's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78007393/12980819) comment.

1. Add  header [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) in server response

In my case its Java server:

```java
        return Response
                .ok(excelFile)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentHeader)
                .header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION)
                .build();
```

2. Parse filename from `Content-Disposition` header:

```dart
  String? tryDecodeFileName(http.Response response) {
    final String? headerValue = response.headers['content-disposition'];
    if (headerValue != null) {
      const String pattern = 'filename*=utf-8' '';
      return Uri.decodeFull(headerValue
          .substring(headerValue.indexOf(pattern) + pattern.length + 2));
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Im my case header value starts with: `attachment;filename="report.xlsx";filename*=utf-8''`.

More info about [filename in content disposition header](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6266#section-5).